# How to use Rabbitmq binder in spring cloud dataflow stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a stream which does launches a task based on given time interval. I want to use rabbit binder with it but I am missing syntax of providing the rabbitmq broker properties. Could someone please help me.

```
Here is the steps and configuration I have.

 1. Imported apps using: app import --uri
    http//bitly/stream-applications-rabbit-maven
 2. Registered a task: app register --name task-sink --type sink --uri file://tasksink.jar
 3. Created stream: stream create foo --definition "triggertask --triggertask.uri=file://task-file.jar --trigger.cron-expression=10 | task-sink" 
 4. stream deploy foo --properties "spring.rabbitmq.host=myhost,         spring.rabbitmq.username=user,spring.rabbitmq.password=pass,     spring.rabbitmq.port=5672,spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=XXX"

When both stream and runtime apps are deployed but I see error on logs saying connection could not be established.
I changed the properties syntax to "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.rabbitmq.host" also but same error.
I am not sure I am not using correct syntax here but below are some different behaviour when i run it on VPN and without VPN.

**Note**: 
Case 1: Both my machines (where SCDF is running and RabbitMQ broker) are in core network (VPN). Even if I run SCDF and RabbitMq on my local machine It does not work and says unable to resolve host.
Case 2: But when I run RabbitMQ and SCDF on my local machine (Not connected to VPN) then it works fine with "spring.rabbitmq.username=user" properties syntax.
Is there any setting which I need to change to connect to different host system?
Thanks in advance for help and suggestion.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.rabbitmq.host=myhost` is correct but since you are passing this to a applications in the Spring Cloud Data Flow DSL, you need to prefix it with the applicaton name, i.e. `app.triggertask.spring.rabbitmq.host` etc. Same for the other aplications. You have a few shortcuts available, see:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_application_properties_when_deploying_a_stream

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties

for details.

Comment: Thank you very much Marius.  Yeh I was missing app.{app name}.  Now my app is able to connect to host.